# java using 100% cpu when application running on jboss 7.2 beta

Tags: java, memory, jboss, cpu

[image]We are running web application on jboss 7.2 beta version with java 8,
service going down after few hours (with in 12-15 hours ) due to high cpu memory usage by java. when we checked performance and cpu usage was 99 % to 100 % (attached image ).
i went through many many solution available on different sites refered this "[debugging JBoss 100% CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449776/debugging-jboss-100-cpu-usage)" to get dump but i am not getting whats going wrong from that dump.

"we have java 6  in sys environmental but configured jboss to use java 8 (changes java home in standalone conf) is this can be a problem or cause to use high memory"

thanks

[image: system performance image when service goes down]

Comment: I would start with `jstat -gccause {pid} 10s` to see if it is GC-ing constantly. Java 8 needs a little more heap than Java 6, so if you didn't change the heap size you might be too close to full memory.

Comment: what is the JVM memory you have configured ?

Comment: set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1G -Xmx1G -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"   this is the java option i see in configuration file of jboss

Comment: HI @Peter Lawrey is above command should be run only when cpu usage goes 100% ? or can i check now also? bcz everything goes normal once i restart jboss it will be stable and okay for another few hours

Comment: @PeterLawrey i  see its showing no Gc .attached sreenshot

Comment: What about the log files? Anything in there indicating exceptions of any sort?

Comment: @Hema , Have you tried this - https://arnhem.luminis.eu/top-threads-plugin-for-jconsole/

Comment: @Hema well that is a bad sign as I would expect to create more garbage for a busy web server. Most likely you have a thread which is in an infinite loop. If you use `jstack` it will tend to place the busiest threads at the top. I would run this 2 or so times to catch where in what thread it is busy. In particular look for threads in a `RUNNING` state.

Comment: i see all threads in waiting state when i get thread dump from jstack

Comment: @PeterLawrey i see all threds are in waiting state in thread dump which i took from jstack  please refer link to see trace " http://www.filetolink.com/f98ce6f957 "

Comment: one solution we are thinking of is forcefully run  garbage collector for every hour with jvm option -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000..can any one suggest is this good idea.(changing configuration for wildfly 13 java 8)

Comment: The DGC is one hour by default.  This only makes a difference is you a) don't GC often b) use RMI extensively.

Comment: I can't download the filetolink.

Comment: it will download as rar and file with in it..when you login with google account to download.

Comment: @PeterLawrey can you try this link https://uploadfiles.io/znsq8

Answer (score 0):

I used IntelliJ to find the interesting RUNNABLE threads.

Looks like something it watching modified files. Not a problem unless this is happening too often.

```
"Thread-82" #114 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000254ca000 nid=0x2468 runnable [0x000000002858f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.GetQueuedCompletionStatus0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.GetQueuedCompletionStatus(WindowsNativeDispatcher.java:1007)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsWatchService$Poller.run(WindowsWatchService.java:586)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

You have a lot of thread tied up trying to perform the following, which might not be using much CPU but doesn't seem very useful. I would investigate which this is doing and why so many threads are blocked on this.

```
"default task-1040" #1270 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001b916000 nid=0x1e1c in Object.wait() [0x0000000075c0e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.framed.AbstractFramedStreamSourceChannel.awaitReadable(AbstractFramedStreamSourceChannel.java:334)
    - locked <0x00000000c9f9a1e0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.xnio.conduits.StreamSourceChannelWrappingConduit.awaitReadable(StreamSourceChannelWrappingConduit.java:71)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.awaitReadable(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:151)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSourceChannel.awaitReadable(DetachableStreamSourceChannel.java:77)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$ReadDispatchChannel.awaitReadable(HttpServerExchange.java:2197)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormEncodedDataDefinition$FormEncodedDataParser.parseBlocking(FormEncodedDataDefinition.java:254)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.parseFormData(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:833)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getParameter(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:706)
    at com.dps.avaya.chat.controller.PrintChat.preparePrintchat(PrintChat.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:592)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:874)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:790)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$649/1162416053.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$650/1376676997.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$650/1376676997.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$650/1376676997.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$650/1376676997.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1349)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```